# Adding a new language to Opera spell-checking

Tags: opera, opera-11, spell-check

How can I add [Persian](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/fa/aspell6-fa-0.11-0.tar.bz2) language spell-checking ability to Opera. It seems that Opera use aspell for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Opera Help](http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/spellchecker.html):

> Opera uses the Hunspell dictionary format, and includes a US English dictionary by default. To add a spell checker dictionary for another language:
>
> 1. Right-click in an input field to display the context menu.
> 2. Select Dictionaries > Add/Remove Dictionaries.
> 3. In the Spell Checker Dictionaries dialog, select the language. You can use the "Quick Find" field at the top of the list to quickly search the full list.
> 4. Check the language you want to use and click "Next".
> 5. Read and accept the license, and click "Next".
> 6. Choose the default dictionary and click "Finish".

The [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net)-based dictionary/spell-checker seems to have been introduced in v10.0.

If the Persian language dictionary cannot be added via the instructions above, try this:

1. Close all running Opera instances.
2. Download the dictionary archive from [here](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/dict-fa) (newer, .oxt file) or [here](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries#Persian_.28Iran.29) (older, .tar.gz file).
3. Locate the Opera directory via `opera:about`.
4. Open the Opera directory, then open the `dictionaries` subfolder (create it if it doesn't exist).
5. Put the downloaded archive in that folder (do not unpack it!)
6. Restart Opera - you should now see the new dictionary in the `Dictionaries` menu.

**Note:** If it doesn't work, close Opera, rename the .oxt or .tar.gz to .zip, reopen Opera and check again.

Comment: Thanks, I placed it in "\Opera x64\locale\fa\dict-fa.zip" and now it works. I hope Opera embed it in next version.

Comment: This info is fairly outdated: Opera migrated to the Chromium engine a long ago, thus spoiling everything.